# Rails: Cache API request with Typhoeus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching, request

How can I cache api requests with Typhoeus gem in Rails? I gave up trying to do it by myself after 2 horus trying.

I have the following code:

```
            hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new
            requests = urls.map do |url|
                request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url, followlocation: true)
                hydra.queue(request)
                request
            end
            hydra.run
```

Their docs say this "Typhoeus includes built in support for caching. In the following example, if there is a cache hit, the cached object is passed to the on_complete handler of the request object."

```
class Cache
  def initialize
    @memory = {}
  end

  def get(request)
    @memory[request]
  end

  def set(request, response)
    @memory[request] = response
  end
end

Typhoeus::Config.cache = Cache.new

Typhoeus.get("www.example.com").cached?
#=> false
Typhoeus.get("www.example.com").cached?
#=> true
```

But I didn't understand where to put this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an initializer to setup the cache.  Something like: (config/initializers/typhoeus.rb)

```
redis = Redis.new(url: "your redis url")
Typhoeus::Config.cache = Typhoeus::Cache::Redis.new(redis, default_ttl: 60)
```

Then in your request you can add caching related options.

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url,
                                method: method,
                                params: params,
                                body: body,
                                headers: request_headers,
                                cache_ttl: 10, 
                                cache_key: "unique_key")

request.run
```

The ttl is in seconds.
The Typhoeus cache_key by default is:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "#{self.class.name}#{base_url}#{hashable_string_for(options)}"
```

They don't document that.  You have to look at the source to figure it out.
It's probably fine, but I demonstrate how to set your own if you want above.

If you want to make a request without using the cache pass cache: false in the options as the cache will be on by default now for all requests.

Answer (score 1):

Just to echo what https://stackoverflow.com/users/215708/jacklin said,

The easiest option that worked for me was:

1. As mentioned before configure `rails cache` with desired cache middleware
2. Point Typhoeus in config file `config/initializers/typhoeus.rb` to use rails cache as shown below

```
require 'typhoeus/cache/rails'
Typhoeus::Config.cache = Typhoeus::Cache::Rails.new
```

3. Thats it.`Typhoeus::Request.new` calls would automatically be cached.

**Side Note if Using Redis**
The response.body object is of type string which I discovered after playing with the Rails cache. Since you want to cache the response and keep referencing the cache, `JSON.parse(response.body)` should give you a hash instead. I believe its a redis thing.